# Does Firebase Cloud Function Trigger Parallel or One by One?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a firebase project.
I have a cloud function that triggers on a change of a value of one of my collection in my RealTimeDB.

If a Bulk of changes are applied in the same time, how does it invoke my cloud function?
Will it invoke the cloud function at the same time , or will it call my cloud function in a sequential order, like one by one.

I am just worried because ,this cloud function has to fetch a value from another collection, which will vary from time to time. And if the order of execution changes, They may fetch a wrong value at that time.

Comment: In parallel, but you can filter the documents of that time-varying collection to only fetch until the desired time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Functions does not guarantee any ordering of events.  Events could be processed in parallel, as there could be multiple server instances handling them simultaneously.  You will need to take this into account if events could be generated rapidly under load.

Comment: If you set a max number of instances to 1, and the function is busy. Will it wait and try again or just skip the execution?

Comment: Setting max instances to 1 does not guarantee that only 1 instance will be used.  It could still go higher temporarily. Read the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#limits_best_practices

Answer (score 0):

Limitations and guarantees on Firestore applies for Firebase too [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#limitations_and_guarantees).

"Ordering is not guaranteed. Rapid changes can trigger function invocations in an unexpected order."

In cases where inbound request volume exceeds the number of existing instances, Cloud Functions may start multiple new instances to handle requests. This automatic scaling behavior allows Cloud Functions to handle many requests in parallel, each using a different instance of your function [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#auto-scaling_and_concurrency).